# Jquery Paginate placing items on second page and no limit on the list so not actually paginating

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

See my JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/frbh9/

So this is inline JS for the paginate.....

```
            <script>
                        $(window).load(
function()
{
  var o=$('#paginate').first(),
      h=o.height(),
      c=$('<div/>').css('width',o.width()).addClass('part'),
      cc,i=1,item,
      p=$('<div id="pagination"></div>').append($('<a/>').text('['+1+']').data({i:0}));

      o.before(p);


  do{
      if(typeof cc=='undefined'){cc=c.clone().appendTo(o);}


    item=o.children().not('.part').first().appendTo(cc.first());

    if(cc.children().length>0 && cc.height()>=h)
    {
      p.append($('<a/>').data({i:i++}).text('['+(i)+']'));
      cc=c.clone().appendTo(o).append(item);
    }
  }while($('#paginate').first().children().not('.part').length>0);

  if($('.part',o).length<2){p.remove();return;}
  $('.part',o).not(':eq(0)').hide();
    $('a',p).click(function(){
      var _this=$(this);
      $('a',_this.parent()).removeClass('current');
      _this.addClass('current');

      $('#paginate>.part').hide().eq(_this.data('i')).show();
      }).first().addClass('current');


  return;
});
            </script>
```

This is external for the list update...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $newItemField = $('#newItem');
    $addButton = $('#add');
    $('ol').sortable();
    $('li').append('<span class="delete">x</span');
    $('ol').delegate('li','mouseover mouseout',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hovered');
    });
    $('ol').delegate('li>.delete','mouseover mouseout',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hovered');
    });
    $('ol').on('click','li>.delete',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $newItemField.keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            addItem();
        }
    });
    $addButton.click(function() {
        addItem();
    });
});
function addItem() {
    if ($newItemField.val() !== '') {
        $newItem = $('<li/>');
        $newItem.text($newItemField.val());
        $deleteButton = $('<span/>').text('x').addClass('delete');
        $newItem.append($deleteButton);
        $newItem.css('background-color','#e4ffef');
        $newItem.appendTo('ol');
        $newItem.animate({backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'},5000);
        $newItemField.val('');
    }
}
```

I am having where by I have a list for tasks to be updated via an input and places it into an OL which works great and it works great with paginate but placing the items onto th seond page....

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because ol element is inside second element of paginate div.
See below(you can see once it renders).

```
<div id="paginate">
  <div class="part" style="width: 960px;"></div>
  <div class="part" style="width: 960px; display: none;">
    <ol class="ui-sortable"></ol>
  </div>
  <div class="part" style="width: 960px; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

so, placing below code will do the trick and work as expected.

```
$(".ui-sortable").appendTo("#paginate div:first-child");
```

**Now it's working...**
http://jsfiddle.net/iashu/Nty7M/

Comment: Thats brilliant, how do I set a limiter on this so it will hit say 10 and create a new page?